# How to add attributes in xml report from junit test?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, testing, junit

I would like to add some attributes in the xml report generated by junit tests to add traceability to my tests

Here's what I would like :

```
class MyTest{
    @Test
    @AddAttribute("key","value")
    fun myTest()
    {

    }
}
```

And then to have this pair ("key","value") added to my report.xml like :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<testsuite name="MyTests" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" time="20.846" timestamp="2020-07-07T15:07:57" hostname="localhost">
  <properties>
    <property name="project" value="app" />
  </properties>
  <testcase name="MyTest" classname="MyTest" time="12.912" key="value" />
</testsuite>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no solution available to solve this. However, if you follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844639/how-to-add-data-to-testcase-with-junit-and-maven-surefire-plugin):, you can at least capture your writings to the console in an `-output.txt` file.

Let's take the following test as an example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestReportingTest {

  @Test
  public void testOutput() {
    System.out.println("Key One: Value");
    System.out.println("Key Two: 1,2,3,4,5");
    assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
  }
}
```

and configuring your Surefire Plugin as the following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

after executing `mvn test`, you'll get a `your.package.TestName-output.txt` file inside `target/surefire-reports` with the following content:

```
Key One: Value
Key Two: 1,2,3,4,5
```

You might want to format your console logs in a way you can easily parse/access them afterward.

This should work both for JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 and is rather related to the Surefire Plugin and not the testing framework. If you are using Gradle as the build system, you can find the correct configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356543/logging-while-testing-through-gradle).